# Cant install Chrome in RHEL 7

Tags: redhat

**I am trying to install Chrome using :**

sudo yum localinstall -y https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm

**but every time I am getting this error:**

Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-FKPkpJ/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm: google-chrome-stable-67.0.3396.62-1.x86_64
Marking /var/tmp/yum-root-FKPkpJ/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package google-chrome-stable.x86_64 0:67.0.3396.62-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/lsb_release for package: google-chrome-stable-67.0.3396.62-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libappindicator3.so.1()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-67.0.3396.62-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/lsb_release for package: google-chrome-stable-67.0.3396.62-1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-67.0.3396.62-1.x86_64 (/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64)
           Requires: libappindicator3.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-67.0.3396.62-1.x86_64 (/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64)
           Requires: /usr/bin/lsb_release
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

**Please Help.**

Answer (score 0):

Taken from https://access.redhat.com/discussions/917293

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
yum -y install redhat-lsb libXScrnSaver
yum -y localinstall google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I just had to use subscription-manager to subscribe and register my system and also update yum with yum check-update.